# Documenting PHP multiple inheritance with PhpDoc

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance, phpdoc

I have multiple inheritance like this one: [Can I extend a class using more than 1 class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php) (let's not discuss this approach itself please) and want my IDE to know about inherited class methods and properties. Is there a way to do it with PhpDoc?

Comment: Is your question more related to PhpDoc or more related to "how displays the appropriate auto-completion inside the editor"?

Comment: I don't like to call this trick multiple inheritance, but rather delegation.

Comment: Savageman, it's about PhpDoc but it's also good to know if there are IDE specific tricks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems there is currently no way to do it easily. I've created a ticket at PhpStorm issue tracker. Maybe they will add support for this feature.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1730

Comment: And finally they did it :)

Comment: This works in PHPStorm simply by using the special phpDoc param `@mixin` like so: `/* @mixin \Another\Class\Or\Namespace */` in the top of the class.

Answer (score 3):

The [`@method`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.method.pkg.html) anotation should be used for classes implementing `__call`. On a related note, for `__get`, `__set` and `__isset`, the [`@property`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html) annotations should be used. The only thing I don't know for sure is whether Eclipse PDT supports these annotations. I know NetBeans does.

Comment: Thanks, I know I can use these but it's hard to redeclare all "inherited" methods and properties one by one. My hope is that there is some kind of PhpDoc I've missed that can delegate class methods and properties to another class.

btw., PhpStorm supports both @property and @method.

Answer (score -3):

there is no support for multiple inheritances at class level. This means you can't extend more than one class at a time. However multiple inheritance is supported in interfaces. An interface can extend an arbitrary number of other interfaces
at a time.