# How is my approach to reuse view logic in my project?

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance, reusability, viewrendering

**Aim**

To implement a proper and efficient view architecture for my project (with maximum reuse of repeated units)

**About my project**

My project involves classes taken by tutors and packs published by tutors. No framework has been used but object orientation and class hierarchies are present for model, controller part.

I have the following modules -

1. Search->Class listings - list of classes displayed in search results.
2. Student room->Class listings - List of classes a student has purchased
3. Search->Class Details - Details page of a class in search module
4. Student room->Class Details - Details page of a class in Student room

and similarly for packs -

5. Search->Pack listings - list of packs displayed in search results.
6. Student room->Pack listings - List of packs a student has purchased.
7. Search->Pack Details - Details page of a pack in search module
8. Student room->Pack Details - Details page of a pack in Student room.

**My current plan**

I am planning to have classes like these:-

```
Class Name                               Contents



commonListingDisplay                     paginationHtml()
                                         smallRatingHtml()
commonDetailsDisplay                     commentsHtml()
                                         largeRatingHtml()

commonClassPackListingDisplay extends commonListingDisplay   
                                         abbreviatedDetailsHtml()

                                         (abbreviated  class/pack                    
                                          details html (class/pack details
                                          ending with ... and a link to the
                                          Class/pack details page).

commonClassPackDetailsDisplay extends commonDetailsDisplay
                                         currently empty

commonClassDisplay                       classDateTimeHtml()
                                         classReminderHtml()

classDetails extends commonClassPackDetailsDisplay,commonClassDisplay
```

- I know PHP does not support multiple inheritance but that can be faked as answered in [Can I extend a class using more than 1 class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php)

**Now taking the example of a module** - While in Search->Class details-
- From the search_class_details.controller.php file, initiate an object of class classDetails, so all the reusable functions are accessible.
- Pass all the variables and the classDetails object to a class_details.view.php (which is the view file of class_details module). The file will look something like:-

```
<div class="class_details">
<h2><?php echo $className ?></h2>
<div><?php echo $classDetails ?></div>
<?php  $classDetailsObj->largeRatingHtml($ratingValue) ?>

<?php $classDetailsObj->commentsHtml($commentsArray) ?>

</div>
```

How does the approach look like? Suggestions from experienced people wanted.

Thanks