# PHP - Faked Multiple inheritance - How to pass multiple parameters to functions

Tags: php, parameter-passing, multiple-inheritance

I found this while searching for how to fake multiple inheritance in PHP (since PHP does not support multiple inheritance directly).

[Can I extend a class using more than 1 class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php/356431#356431)

Here is the complete code given there:-

```
class B {
    public function method_from_b($s) {
        echo $s;
    }
}

class C {
    public function method_from_c($s) {
        echo $s;
    }
}

class A extends B
{
  private $c;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->c = new C;
  }

  // fake "extends C" using magic function
  public function __call($method, $args)
  {
    $this->c->$method($args[0]);
  }
}


$a = new A;
$a->method_from_b("abc");
$a->method_from_c("def");
```

**The problem**
The example given here considers only one parameter for the function `C::method_from_c($s)`. It works fine with one parameter but I have several functions of `class C`, some having 2, some having 3 parameters like this:-

```
class C {
    public function method_from_c($one,$two) {
        return $someValue;
    }

    public function another_method_from_c($one,$two, $three) {
        return $someValue;
    }
}
```

And I **do not** want to change anything in Class C's function definition (It must accept those many parameters). E.g. I do not want to use func_get_args() inside my `C::method_from_c($s,$two)` like this:-

```
public function method_from_c() 
{

     $args = func_get_args();

     //extract params from $args and then treat each parameter
}
```

What to do inside the `__call()` function of `class A` so that it works. I want to be able to call `Class C` functions like `$obj->method_from_c($one,$two);`

Thanks
Sandeepan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
function __call($method, $args) {
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this->c, $method), $args);
}
```

note that this won't perform as well though.

Comment: The reference operator for $this->c is redundant

Comment: @sandeepan: actually I'm not sure, but I vaguely remember to have read somewhere that $foo->$bar() performs better than using call_user_func.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-method-array.php)?

```
public function __call($method_name, $args)
{
   return call_user_method_array($method_name, $this->c, $args);
}
```

Comment: Raoul Duke's answer is better than mine - (the call_user_method fns are deprecated)