# Programmatically check if method is public

Tags: php, function, public-method

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a function is public or protected in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160901/how-to-check-if-a-function-is-public-or-protected-in-php)

Is there a function that checks if giver method of given class is public?

I know `method_exists()`, but it does not work how I want to. If there isn't how can I check that?

Comment: What about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160901/how-to-check-if-a-function-is-public-or-protected-in-php

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php