# Marking classes for dependency container injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am using a modified copy of [yadif](https://github.com/beberlei/yadif) as my dependency injection framework.

Currently, I have created an abstract class called AContainerAware which is similiar to symfony2's [ContainerAware](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.html):

```
abstract class AContainerAware{
    protected $_container;

    public function setContainer(Container $container){
       $this->_container = $container;
    }

    protected function get($component){
       //return a component from $this->_container;
    }
}
```

This works well in most cases. I just have class who require the container to extend AContainerAware, and the container is automatically injected by the DI framework during object creation using `setContainer()`. I can then easily get components from the container.

The issue is when working with third party vendor packages. In those cases, for example writing an extension for [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org) requires me to extend the `Twig_Extension` class, which means I can't extend `AContainerAware` to get access to the container.

I am considering whether to turn `AContainerAware` into an interface `IContainerAware`. Since classes can implement multiple interfaces, `IContainerAware` should be implementable in most cases. The only issue with this approach is that one cannot write any code for `setContainer()` and `get()` in an interface, so it is repetitive to have to implement the exact code for those functions in each class that requires the container. It also poses maintainance issues if `setContainer()` and `get()` were to change in the future.

Is there a better way to mark a class for container injection?

Comment: You can extend multiple classes like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php

Comment: I don't really like faking multiple inheritance with `__call()` though, doesn't seem very elegant to me. It also requires a copy of one of the classes to be instantiated within the class, which kind of defeats dependency injection.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PHP traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) which were introduced in PHP 5.4.

Traits enable horizontal reuse of code, whereas inheritance is vertical reuse. A class can use multiple traits, whereas you can only inherit one parent class.