# Generic comment system in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have in my Symfony 2.1 RC app a simple `Comment` model (using Doctrine 2). Every comment has a `user` and a `message`.

Currently, the `CommentBundle` manages comments on articles. I'd like it to be more generic to be able to comment any kind of entity without copying code across different bundles dedicated to comments...

For this to work, I also need a way to reference any entity from the comment one. I think having two fields `entity_type` and `entity_id` can be a nice solution. However, I can't get the object from these without mapping `entity_type` to classes manually and using the `find` method.

So how do I reference an entity from a comment ? And how can I create generic behavior working  on several entities ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a abstract base class entity called `Commentable` and create entities that inherit `Commentable` such as `Document` or `Post`.

Since `Document` and `Post` are derived from `Commentable`, you can create a one to many relationship between the entities `Commentable` and `Comment` respectively.

Make sure to include in your base class ORM annotations for inheritance:

```
@InheritanceType
@DiscriminatorColumn
@DiscriminatorMap
```

Examples can be found on [Doctrine Project Inheritance Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Comment: Is there a way to allow multiple generic behaviours like this using this way ? For instance, if I want a Document to be Commentable and Taggable ?

Comment: PHP will not let you create multiple inheritance relationships directly. However you can use the magic function __call() to work around this. Here is an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php

Comment: Right but Doctrine can't recognize a Document as both Taggable and Commentable ?

Comment: Correct. Doctrine won't recognize it. However, another way you can achieve this is through multiple level inheritance by making Taggable extend Commentable and make the rest of your entities extend Commentable. If there's very little need to make Taggable and Commentable seperate entities, you might want to consider just merging them into one entity.

Comment: And what if I've got a User class that already uses a DiscriminatorMap? I want to make both the entities Order and all User types (Customer, Admin, Editor) commentable. In that case inheritance doesn't seem an option.