# Can we extend more than one class in php?

Tags: php

I have tried to extend the two class with the same instance.it's not working..is there any way to do it..?

```
class Watermark extends PDF_Rotate, MyPDF{
//Your Code
}
```

Comment: Not like that, no.

Comment: Here a good answer using traits http://stackoverflow.com/a/6466751/6286432

Comment: This may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php/6466751#6466751

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not **extend** two or more classes but you can **implement** more than one **interface** in php. Like below

```
<?php

    class SomeClass extends HelloDolly implements HelloInterface, DollyInterface {
        // do your stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend **only one** parent in your class. From PHP Doc:

> A class can inherit the methods and properties of another class by
>   using the keyword extends in the class declaration. It is not possible
>   to extend multiple classes; a class can only inherit from one base
>   class.

But you can use for example many interfaces or traits in one class definition. From PHP Doc:

> Classes may implement more than one interface if desired by separating
>   each interface with a comma.