# PHP Class Dependent on another Class

Tags: php

I have the following problem - lets say I have a class named `Database`

```
class Database
{
   public function insert(...)
   {
    //insert something in the database
   }
}
```

And I have a class named `User`

```
class User
{
   public function register(..)
   {
       //validate the user , and insert him
       //here i need to call insert() function from Database class
   }
}
```

Is there a simple way in which I can call the insert method inside the User class?

Comment: `dependency injection` - perhaps might be of interest http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html and / or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: Does your `Database` class need to be instanciated? Why not make it static?

Comment: Syscall , no i can make it static , then just include it and call Database::insert(...) ? Is this correct , i`m new to OOP

Comment: Yes. `static public function insert()`, then in `register()`, use `Database::insert(...)`.

Comment: PetarPirev, @RamRaider is right, dependency injection is the way to go. **Make your classes' dependencies explicit**.

Comment: Syscall , thanks , how to mark your comment as a correct answer ?

Comment: ishegg , i heard about that , but it`s like complex to me , with these controllers and such

Comment: Petar, it certainly has a learning curve, but trust me, you will be thanking yourself in the long run. It'll be much more maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `dependency injection` you would typically do it something like this

```
class Database
{
   public function insert(...)
   {
    //insert something in the database
   }
}


class User
{
   private $db;
   public function __construct($db){
        $this->db=$db
   }
   public function register(..)
   {
       //validate the user , and insert him
       //here i need to call insert() function from Database class

       $this->db->insert();
   }
}

$db=new Database();
$usr=new User( $db );
$usr->register();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make an object in the user class and call the method in it like

```
class User
{
public function register(..)
 {
   //validate the user , and insert him
   //here i need to call insert() function from Database class
 $useit= new Database; //assign an object of type database
  $useit->insert();  //call the method like this
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an instance of the class you want to import in the constructor of the class you're importing it to.

```
class User {
    private $database;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->database = new Database;
    }

    public function register() {
        $this->database->insert();
    }
}

class Database {
    public function insert() {
    }
}

$user = new User;
$user->register();
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php) answer should help. You can access all methods and properties of the Database class by referencing `$this->database`.

Comment: Clear way to do this is dependency injection through constructor method. otherwise you can't do unit testing and this is bad pattern