# How to extend multiple things for User.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am new to coding and I am trying to extend `\TCG\Voyager\Models\User` and `Authenticatable` implements `MustVerifyEmail` together but I do not know how to do it.

I have tried class `User` extends `\TCG\Voyager\Models\User`, `Authenticatable` implements `MustVerifyEmail` together but that doesn't work for me.

I have created 2 seperate classes and that does not let me either.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I extend a class using more than 1 class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend two (or more) classes in `PHP`, just one. A solution could be:

- `Class A` extends `Class B`
- `Class B` extends `Class C`

This way, `Class A` would also be extending `Class C` (through `Class B`).

In your case:

- `User` extends `\TCG\Voyager\Models\User` and implements `MustVerifyEmail`
- `\TCG\Voyager\Models\User` extends `Authenticatable`

---

This is one of the reasons, Traits were introduced in the PHP world (are not the same though).

Comment: So how would I write it. Im new to this so its very hard to understand.